# find index of item in multiline List

Tags: erlang

I am iterating over a list of files, storing the contents in a list and then searching for the position of a word "blue()" in that list, here is the code i'm using to find the word:

```
Item = "blue()",
{ok, Device} = file:read_file([File]),
Li = string:tokens(erlang:binary_to_list(Device), "\n"),
Nlist = lists:map(fun (X) ->string:strip(X) end, Li),
Index = string:str(Nlist, [Item]),
io:format("~p", [Index]).
```

This simply does not work, it returns "0" I thought maybe it was to do with spaces, so i tried to remove them and to no success, I have ran out of ideas after working on it for about 2 hours :/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `lists:map` and `string:strip`

```
lists:map(fun(E) -> string:strip(E) end, List)

7> lists:map(fun(E) -> string:strip(E) end, ["hello", " world"]).      
["hello","world"]
```

Comment: already tried, this works on a custom list that has no newlines \r\n but it wont work on a list that has newlines.. try to read a file line by line and store it in to a list, now try to find the index of "blue" in that list.. it wont happen :)

Comment: @ace007: `string:tokens/2` actually accepts multiple token characters **and doesn't care about their order**, so you can split on all sorts of newlines like so: `string:tokens(String, "\r\n")`

Answer (score 0):

The `string` module expects a flat list to work with. You're passing it a list of lists. If your goal is simply to identify the index of the term "blue()", you can just use the re module without all the string splitting zaniness.

```
Data = file:read_file([File]),
case re:run(Data, "blue()") of  % Note that re takes binaries, strings, and iolists as input
    {match, [{StartIndex, StopIndex}]} -> io:format("~p", [StartIndex]);
    nomatch -> io:format("Item not found.")
end.
```

Alternatively, without changing much, you can look for the term "blue()" in Nlist like so (prints the line number and character offset of the term):

```
find_terms(Item, L) -> find_terms(Item, L, 1).

find_terms(Item, [], N) ->
    ok;
find_terms(Item, [String|Rest], LineNumber) ->
    case string:str(String, Item) of
        0 -> % string:str returns 0 when the substring is not found
            find_terms(Item, Rest, LineNumber + 1);
        Index ->
            io:format("~p:~p", [Line, Index]),
            find_terms(Item, Rest, LineNumber + 1);
    end.
```

And you would call that with `find_terms("blue()", Nlist)`

Comment: about the second snipped of code, where do I define the word I'm looking for? and how would i add this to my code i have to declare this function in the -export secion but how many args does it take because there is 3 of the same name... new to erlang :) not enjoying it either,,

Comment: Fixed the function declaration to include a search term. For your export, you would do `-export([find_terms/2]).`; the third parameter is for internal use only, so you don't need to expose it. However, you can use the same model to supply default values for optional arguments. Think of it as an assembly line: each step adds a required piece. Having functions with the same name is fine so long as they take a different number of arguments. For example, to export both find_terms functions, do: `-export([find_terms/2, find_terms/3]).`.

Comment: Also, if you haven't found it yet, I highly recommend this site for beginners (also available as a book): http://learnyousomeerlang.com/